# dealing with dimensions in scikit-learn tree.decisiontreeclassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, computer-vision, scikit-learn

I am trying to do a decision tree using `scikit-learn` with three dimensional training data and two dimensional target data. As a simple example, imagine an rgb image. lets say my target data is 1's and 0's, where 1's represent the presence of a human face, and 0's represent the absence. Take for example:

```
red         green        blue        face presence  

1000        0001         0011        0000    
0110        0110         0001        0110    
0110        0110         0000        0110
```

An array of the rgb data would represent the training data, and the 2d array would represent my target classes (face, no-face).

In Python these arrays may look like:

```
rgb = np.array([[[1,0,0,0],[0,1,1,0],[0,1,1,0]],
               [[0,0,0,1],[0,1,1,0],[0,1,1,0]],
               [[0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,0]]])

face = np.array([[0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,0],[0,1,1,0]])
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import tree
dt_clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
dt_clf = dt_clf.fit(rgb, face)
```

This throws this error:

> Found array with dim 3. Expected <= 2

I have tried reshaping and flattening the data several ways and get another error:

> Number of labels=xxx does not match number of samples

Does anyone know how I can use `tree.DecisionTreeClassifier` to accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have figured it out. It's not very pretty. Maybe someone can offer some help cleaning up the code. Basically, I needed to organize the rgb data to be an array of 12 3-element arrays, or shape=(12,3). For example...

```
np.hsplit(np.dstack(rgb).flatten(), len(face.flatten()))
```

I also flatten the face data, so my final fit call becomes...

```
dt_clf = dt_clf.fit(np.hsplit(np.dstack(rgb).flatten(), len(face.flatten())), 
                    face.flatten())
```

Now I can test a new dataset and see if it works. The target image indicated face presence when both red and green pixels were shown, so a good test might be...

```
red         green        blue 

1100        1100         0011  
1100        1100         0001  
0000        0000         0000
```

or...

```
predict = np.array([[[1,1,0,0],[1,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
                    [[1,1,0,0],[1,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
                    [[0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,0,0]]])
```

so...

```
predicted = dt_clf.predict(np.hsplit(np.dstack(predict).flatten(),
                           len(face.flatten())))
```

and to get it back in the proper dimensions...

```
predicted = np.array(np.hsplit(predicted, face.shape[0]))
```

which yields us

```
array([[1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Wonderful! Now to see if this works on something bigger. Please feel free to offer suggestions to make this cleaner.

Comment: As far as making the code cleaner, check out my answer to my question in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31886700/as-formula-specifier-for-sklearn-tree-decisiontreeclassifier-in-python/31899000#31899000)...