# as_formula specifier for sklearn.tree.decisiontreeclassifier in Python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree, patsy

I was curious if there is an as_formula specifier (like in `statsmodels`) for `sklearn.tree.decisiontreeclassifier` in Python, or some way to hack one in. Currently, I must use

```
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X, Y)
```

but I would prefer to have something like

```
clf = clf.fit(formula='Y ~ X', data=df)
```

The reason is that I would like to specify more than one X without having to do a lot of array shaping. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's currently not possible, but it would be great to have a patsy interface for scikit-learn. I don't think anyone is working on it at the moment, though.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the information. Although there is no current `Patsy` interface for `sklearn`, `Patsy` easily provides the functionality I need. As an example...

```
from sklearn import tree
from patsy import dmatrix

red = [1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0]
green = [0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0]
blue = [0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]

y = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0]

X = dmatrix('red + green + blue + 0')

dt_clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
dt_clf = dt_clf.fit(X, y)

pred_r = [1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
pred_g = [1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
pred_b = [0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]

test = dmatrix('pred_r + pred_g + pred_b + 0')
dt_clf.predict(test)
```

Perhaps even more convenient is the fact that `sklearn` plays well with `pandas`. Using the same data as above...

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['red'] = red
df['green'] = green
df['blue'] = blue
df['y'] = y

dt_clf = dt_clf.fit(df[['red','green','blue']], df['y'])
dt_clf.predict(test)
```

Hopefully this helps someone in the same situation as me.

note: be very careful that the sequence of Xs remains the same. For example, don't train as df[['red','green','blue']] then predict (df[['blue','green','red']]. May seem obvious, but an easy way to mess things up.